# How to modify default wordpress comment form in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, captcha

I want to customize the default wordpress form(popup) by adding captcha functionality
and modifying the CSS of it as per my child themes requirement. Also I dont want to use any plugin.

I am newbie in wordpress and just started to working on this.

How can I do this? Need Help.

Comment: Just check if there is any file with a name comments.php in your theme directory. If existing you can check the identity or the class of the comment section elements and modify them in style.css

Answer (score 0):

there are two way one is the you can  simple  change by detecting the  css class for form and adding them to your style.css file

other thing is that  go to wpinclude  folder on root and find commenttemplate.php at bottom make the changes in form